# UIView bypass event to another uiview

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller

1. A is a custom `UIView`
   B is `UIImagePickerController.view`, and this `UIImagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO`
2. `A.frame = B.frame`
3. `[B addSubview:A]`

Now the question is: When I tap the screen, I want A and B response the tap event at the same time. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: If theirs frames are equal, why not delegates?

Comment: cause for UIImagePickerController I don't know which method will trigger "show the focus square" so I don't know which method should I send.

Answer (score 1):

This will require subclassing the `UIWindow` and overriding the `sendEvent:` method. The default implementation travels in the view hierarchy and stops after the first responder which passes the hit test. Your implementation will have to continue down the responder chain.

Comment: I inherited the UIImagePickerController and added A to this controller, then override "- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event" to send event to both, this makes work !